# react hooks must be called in a react function - how do I change syntax to correct?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

this is my first react project and I am trying to create a function based component for a menu bar.
When I try to access useNavigate() I get an error "react hooks must be called in a react function."

how do I change the current code I have to use the line

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

below is my function

```
    export const MenuBar = () => (
  <div>
    <Typography variant="h5">Ninja Notes</Typography>
    <Typography variant="h3">{testItem}</Typography>
  </div>
);
```

then further more, on another page I am trying to use

```
import { MenuBar } from "./MenuBar";
```

Comment: `const navigate = useNavigate();` Where is this line being used? If you put it inside MenuBar, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `useNavigate` inside the component that uses it.

If you want to use it inside the `MenuBar` try

```
  export const MenuBar = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate(); // but no need to use the hook if you do not use the navigate variable inside the component.
    return (
      <div>
        <Typography variant="h5">Ninja Notes</Typography>
        <Typography variant="h3">{testItem}</Typography>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: thank you, I just had to add the curly braces and a return ()

Comment: would you still consider this a function based component using arrow function?

Comment: @solarissf yes. It is a functional component, and it is an arrow function (*although it does not have to be an arrow function to be considered a functional component*).